# Can window.location ever evaluate to false?

Tags: javascript, deobfuscation

I've been working through an obfuscated script and I am currently analyzing some functions. I think the IIFE function is dead code that was injected into the script since there are not variables from other scopes being modified and no return value that is being used. That being said, is it ever possible for the expression `window.location` to be evaluated as `false`?

```js
function JJ(J, L) {
  // Dead Code Function?
  (function() {
    if (!window["location"]) {
      var J = RegExp("Edge")["exec"](window["navigator"]["userAgent"]);
      if (J) return J[1];
      if (!document["all"]) return void(0);
      if (!document["compatMode"]) return 5
    }
  })();
  var S = parseInt(J["substring"](L, L + 8), 16);
  L += 8;
  return {
    "value": S,
    ZJ: L
  }
}
```

Comment: It's probably not guarding against `false`, but rather against `null`, `undefined` or one of the other ["falsy" values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).

Comment: `window` can be undefined if the code is run in a server environment (e.g., Node.js).

Comment: In a web worker you can define `self["window"] = {}` and `window.location` will be undefined.

Comment: Something else is strange: The IIFE has `return` statements, but the return value is never used.